# The updateCursor doesn't update all the cells in the shp, just some of them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor

Don't know for sure what is happening, but when I use arcpy.UpdateCursor it only writes some of the lines and not all of the lines.

The code is:

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("FInal1a1.shp")
for row in cursor:
    row.setValue("NomArq",n)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Final1a1.shp",['Id','Diametro','NomArq']) as Buscador:
        with open(nombarch2,"a+")as c:
            for row in Buscador:
                for cell in row:
                    conv= str(cell)
                    c.write(conv)
                    c.write(" ")
                c.write("\n")
            f.close
```

And the output is something like this: (it's the third row)

```
2 75 21 
2 75 0 
3 100 0 
3 100 0 
3 200 0 
2 75 21 
2 75 21 
3 100 0 
3 100 0 
3 200 0 
2 75 21 
2 75 21 
3 100 21 
3 100 0 
3 200 0 
2 75 21 
2 75 21 
3 100 21 
3 100 21 
3 200 0 
2 75 21 
2 75 21 
3 100 21 
3 100 21 
3 200 21 
2 90 32
```

Comment: Since you're using a DA search cursor, why aren't you using a DA update cursor?  Please update the question with the exact ArcGIS release.

Comment: you have two variables "row" with two different cursors and you update your row before you enter the search cursor in the same loop

Comment: i already change the "row" variable but the script does the same... i will try with da.updatecursor right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is you put SearchCursor in the UpadteCursor's loop.

You can repair follow under code block.

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("FInal1a1.shp")
for row in cursor:
    row.setValue("NomArq",n)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Final1a1.shp",['Id','Diametro','NomArq']) as Buscador:
    with open(nombarch2,"a+")as c:
        for row in Buscador:
            for cell in row:
                conv= str(cell)
                c.write(conv)
                c.write(" ")
            c.write("\n")
        f.close
```